# Where is the Client Keys in Sentry

Tags: sentry

I'm new to sentry.
Where is the Client Keys (DSN) in Sentry?

In my Project page, there are issues, Overview, UserFeedback, Releases Tabs.
However there is no Settings.

Sentry says
"Looking for the DSN for an SDK? You'll find that under [Project] » Settings » Client Keys."

Where is Settings?
thank you.

Comment: Did you test my answer?

Answer (score 3):

On Sentry Panel Click on ***YourProjectName*** on Top-Left of Page to see menu,

then click on **Organization settings**,

then Click on **Project** on left side of the page and choose your ***project***,

then on the left menu find **Client Keys (DSN)** and copy **DSN**.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no "Settings" Tab, then you don't have permission for it.

Make sure the admin gives you the correct access rights.